# I need a v-slider with the value decreasing from left to right. How can I achieve this?

Tags: vuetify.js

Currently I am using negative values for max and min and trying to hide the negative sign inside the thumb label. This is less than optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pull request that addresses this problem

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/pull/6809