# How do I make changes to the v-slider component and test it in my app?

Tags: vuetify.js

I tried editing inside node_modules but the files are taken from dist and src seems to be ignored.

I tried npm run build to see if I can push my changes to dist but that doesn't work either as other dependencies seem to be missing.

UPDATE:

I followed the instructions about set up dev env in the Contributing section of the docs.

Made the changes and did yarn and yarn build

But the dist folder is identical to the one without my changes

What gives?

Comment: You shouldn't change files in the node_modules folder. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I want a decreasing v-slider (max value on the left and min on the right).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55278597/i-need-a-v-slider-with-the-value-decreasing-from-left-to-right-how-can-i-achiev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instructions in the set up dev env in the Contributing section work.

After running "yarn build" in the cloned repository folder, you can copy the contents of the dist folder under packages/vuetify to the dist folder under node_modules/vuetify of the app being developed and your changes can be tested.

You can also do npm run build inside packages/vuetify for subsequent changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit code in node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VSlider/VSlider.js
Then, you install patch-package and execute path package vuetify
Delete node modules and execute yarn to create new node modules
Last, yarn serve, you see your code is work
https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package