# How do I install vuetify directly from github?

Tags: vuetify.js

When I try with

```
npm install vuetifyjs/vuetify#v1.5.2
```

I get "Cannot find package".

UPDATE:

There is a packages folder under which there is a vuetify directory.

I tried npm installing that folder. Everything appeared to go well until I started the dev server.

Now in the console log I see:

```
[Vuetify] Multiple instances of Vue detected
```

Seems to be related to https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4068 but I cannot tell what the solution is at this point.

Comment: "I tried npm installing that folder", how specifically did you do that?

Comment: from a local checkout of the git repo

Comment: hmm so you mean you cloned the repo, and then ran `npm install` in the `packages/vuetify/` folder to install its dependencies locally? it seems like you're changing the premise of your question. otherwise, this would be a very roundabout way to install the vuetify package

Comment: I cloned the repo. Then I ran npm install <cloned-folder>/packages/vuetify to install it inside my app. But that didn't work either (something about 2 Vues). How are the contents of the dist folder generated when I install from npm? Is that part of the installation procedure or is that downloaded? I need to duplicate that with the changes in my source code. I don't understand how I have changed the premise of my original question.

Comment: This is no longer installing "directly from github". You're attempting to clone the repo, build the project, and include that build in your own project. It's still an answerable question, but outside the original scope of this post. You should update your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55278918/how-do-i-make-changes-to-the-v-slider-component-and-test-it-in-my-app) to include clear and explicit steps for what you have tried and exactly what errors you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [`package.json` file](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/package.json), the package doesn't have a `name` property, which it would need to have for you to be able to install it from GitHub.

So the short answer is that you can't install vuetify directly from GitHub via `npm`.

---

However, you can install it directly from npm:

```
npm install vuetify@1.5.2
```

Comment: But I need a way I can change the source and build and test. Changing the source with an npm install does not seem to take effect as it gets everything from dist. Any ideas on what steps I need to make this work?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55278918/how-do-i-make-changes-to-the-v-slider-component-and-test-it-in-my-app

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue to use my own version of Vuetify, waiting for my pull request being accepted.
Here what I did:
I build the vuetify project with my fix.

```
 yarn
 yarn build
```

Then I took the content of 'packages/vuetify' and put it in a new git repository. I remove the .gitignore to be able to commit built files (/es5, /lib, /lib-temp, /dist)

Finally I add this git repository to my project to replace my vuetify version:

```
 npm install git+https://gitlab.com/GITLABUSERNAME/REPOSITORYNAME.git
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't install vuetify directly from GitHub but you can edit code in 1 component node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VSlider/VSlider.js Then, you install patch-package and execute path package vuetify Delete node modules and execute yarn to create new node modules Last, yarn serve, you see your code is work

https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package